# Need advice on amount of threads used

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Hey I was hoping some one could explain something to me. I'm new to programming and so far in the program I am writing I haven't done anything with threading, but when I look at the resource monitor in windows 7 it shows 18 threads for my program.

My program is just under 1MB at this point uses about 10,000kb of private memory on average and rarely hits 1% of my cpu usage. The program still runs great but I was just a little confused and wanted some insight on this.

Should this even be something I should be concerned about and if so, what should I be looking at that might cause so many threads being used?

Comment: What you're doing is known as "premature optimization". Google for that expression and you'll find that you should not worry about this.

Comment: Let the CLR determine how many threads it should use. If you're debugging this through visual studio, some of those are debug threads and such anyway.

Comment: You may not be threading yourself.. but libraries will be. Turn on the Threads column in Task Manager and look at how many some other programs use. For example, Chrome has 99 threads happening for me right now :)

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. I'm really not overly worried about these things but since I am new to programming I want to try to not learn any bad habits and be informed about what I am looking at. Everything I found when googling suggested that the lower the threads used the better and suggested staying around 2. When looking at other programs usage that didn't sound right so I wanted to ask.

Comment: _the lower the threads used the better and suggested staying around 2_ sounds like a suggestion with limited use? What if you have code that could be parallelized and you have 64 cores available with most of them idle mode? It's true that you shouldn't fire out threads (on your own) as if they were candy - esp. if they idle most of the time. But it's also true (as already stated) that it's the best to let the CLR decide. **Your** job is simply telling the CLR where multithreading **could** be applied and then let the CLR decide **how** (at least that's true 90/100)

Answer (score 6):

The threads you are seeing may well not be your own threads, they will be owned by the clr and will be handling things like garbage collection.

I'd suggest that you don't need to worry about thread management. If you need to program multiple tasks happening at once, then take a look at the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). Multi threaded programming is hard, learn about it only when you really have to.

Comment: +1. If interested - VS have "Threads" view which may shed some light on what each thread is for.